# NestJS dynamic configuration loader

Tags: typescript, dynamic, module, configuration, nestjs

I'm trying to build a **dynamic nest module** with the same functionality like the built-in **ConfigService** that can load the configuration from a **REST API**.
I have digested the relevant NestJS documentation and [this dev.to article](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370), I used the latter heavily for inspiration.

Unfortunately, I get the below error message which I don't understand - I'm definitely providing the `'CONFIGURATION'` provider to the `ConfigService`.
How can I further **debug** this problem ?  Is there a way to see **NestJS's DI machinery** in action ?  I can only set breakpoints in my own code which isn't teaching me anything.

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConfigService (?). Please make sure that the argument CONFIGURATION at index [0] is available in the ConfigService context.

Potential solutions:
- If CONFIGURATION is a provider, is it part of the current ConfigService?
- If CONFIGURATION is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ConfigService?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing CONFIGURATION */ ]
  })
```

Here's my code :

#### application-deployment-options.ts

```ts
export interface ApplicationDeploymentOptions {
  applicationName: string
  deploymentVariant: string | undefined
  version: string
}
```

#### config.module.ts

```ts
@Global()
@Module({})
export class ConfigModule {
  public static registerAsync(options: ApplicationDeploymentOptions): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ConfigModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CONFIGURATION',
          useFactory: async () => ConfigService.loadConfig(options),
        },
        ConfigService,
      ],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    }
  }
}
```

#### config.service.ts

```ts
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  private readonly nestConfigService: NestConfigService

  constructor(@Inject('CONFIGURATION') config: Record<string, any>) {
    this.nestConfigService = new NestConfigService(config)
  }

  public static async loadConfig(appDeploymentOptions: ApplicationDeploymentOptions): Promise<Record<string, any>> {
    const axiosResult = await axios.get(process.env.CONFIG_SERVICE_URL || 'http://localhost:4000/', {
      params: appDeploymentOptions,
    })

    return axiosResult.data
  }

  public get<T>(key: string): T | undefined {
    return this.nestConfigService.get<T>(key)
  }
}
```

#### the consumer

```ts
const appDeployOptions: ApplicationDeploymentOptions = {
  applicationName: 'number-authority',
  deploymentVariant: undefined,
  version: '1.0.1',
}

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.registerAsync(appDeployOptions), LoggingModule],
  controllers: [NumberAuthorityController],
  providers: [NumberAuthorityService],
})
export class NumberAuthorityModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you have `ConfigService` in an `imports` array, so it is trying to be resolved in a different way. Only modules should be in the `imports` array. If you need access to a provider from a module, the module should have the provider in the `exports` and `providers` arrays, and the module should be in the `imports` array of the module that wants to make use of this provider.